# GNU GRUB version 2.03-6 parrot4 in windows 10,

Tags: operating-system

I'm really download a security editing of parrot and use USB Flash to complete process.
I'm restart windows10 and press F5, then the screen display a
GNU GURB Boot version 2.03-6 parrot4.

I don't understand how i can installation a system with the GNU GRUB problem not solve :)

I have a goid place in windows to add parrot as a basic os?